# Is a user name advertising for a service allowed here?

Tags: discussion, user-accounts

I just ran across [this user name](https://askubuntu.com/users/494708/make-me-a-website-net) which is a clear advertisement for a service...

*Is this allowed here on AU?*

<sub>Yes, I found [this](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/8194/is-there-a-way-to-report-users-based-on-their-user-names) already...</sub>

Comment: The user has since changed their name (as of a few minutes ago, I guess). The old username (as brought up in chat) was "make-me-a-website.net".

Comment: FWIW my personal opinion is "meh".

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Using a domain name as your nick won't actually link anybody anywhere other than your profile. It won't attract Google rank or any other benefit.

And in this case it looks like they've already change it by their own volition.

Comment: Well, I learned a new word today. And it wasn't of my own volition!

Comment: First time I ever had a "You can only accept an answer in 10 minutes"... Good Heavens you're fast!  **;-)**

Comment: Not sure if these names are allowed or not my self, based on this question alone it may be fine, but I found this guy today with his website as a name, I will just leave it here for you to act on, or not, as I am not sure what to do with it http://askubuntu.com/users/395258/freesoftwareservers